# How do you render 2 models on a view in asp.net mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page that will have some textboxes that will save to a table called `Values`, let's say.  The textboxes that I display will populate the selection from a dropdownlist.  This dropdownlist will get its values from another table in the database called `DropDownListValues`.  I am assuming that my controller would be built on the `Values` model but I guess I am a little bit confused as to how I will give the values to the dropdownlist.  Do I store it in a `ViewBag` or render a partial view? Just trying to find the best approach here as I am a little new to asp.net mvc.

Comment: my understanding is that you have to create a new ViewModel to hold your 2 models. that way you can keep your strong-typing.

Comment: I can have a strongly typed partial view, would that work? that seems like the cleanest solution to me, otherwise, I do like what you have suggested

Comment: Please don't use `ViewBag`.  You should nearly _always_ use a view model when your question is some permutation of "How do I pass this data back and forth between the Controller and the View?"  Post your relevant code and I'm sure someone will be happy to help you refactor to use a view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ViewModel`.  This was in a comment but I cannot accept that as an answer so I decided to post an answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you store them in viewBag

```
  ViewBag.CompanyTypes = _Repository.GetCompanyTypes().
                Select(p => new SelectListItem { Text = p.CompanyType1, Value = p.CompanyTypeID.ToString() });
```

and use it like that:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.CompanyTypeID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CompanyTypes )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use both of them and question is store in ViewBag or render partial view? answer: yes, you can use both of them when you need. And  you can prepare specific extensions for example for cities, offices, few popular users etc.